# Spring AMQP RPC vs Spring AMQP Request/Reply Messaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have been learning how to use spring framework and so far so good. I have created an app from Spring Initializr - http://start.spring.io/ and i have been able to setup numerous controllers and even setup security and everything works out.

I am running my app on Apache Tomcat. I now want to use Spring AMQP and the way i want to use it is like this. I shall execute a controller method in the browser and that adds a message in the queue which should be consumed by a consumer,possibly a threadpool powered consumer and return the result to the user.

For instance i want to add a message to the queue and return json to the user.
Since i executed the add message from a  controller, i am expecting to show the response to the user.

After going through the rabbit mq docs, i think RPC would help me publish the message to the queue and it shall be consumed and the result returned to teh user. I setup the rabbit mq example using php and i saw it work.

However, upon looking through the spring amqp docs,i came across this three

-Message Listener https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#containerAttributes

-Listener Concurrency https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#listener-concurrency

-Request/Reply Messaging https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply

-RPC https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html

My question is,if i wanted to let the user get the result, would i pick RPC or Request/Reply Messaging or are they the same thing?

Second, in the last RPC example i did, i started the listener separately like `java_listener.java` to be able to consume the messages.

Since i started my app with spring intilizr and i am running tomcat, will i need to start the consumer separately from the tomcat process?.

Thanks.

Comment: In the examples you cite, I think that the "RPC" implementation is really just a bit of extra abstraction around a request-response messaging channel implemented with AMQP. The decision whether you wanted RPC or request-response would thus (IIRC) turn on whether you needed that extra abstraction, or whether you were happy to work directly with message bodies and destinations. Since the underlying channel is the same, I wouldn't expect there to be much difference in throughput -- it's more a matter of which is more expressive and maintainable in your application.

Comment: @KevinBoone Thanks for the comment. When it comes to the consumer, do i need to run it outside of my spring application?.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to construct the customer inside your Spring application but, to be honest, I haven't tried.

Comment: Yes, the consumer can run in the same process, but then the question would be why do you need a broker and RPC at all? Your controller can simply call the service directly. You don't need **Remote** Procedure Call if the service is **local**.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for the comment. I will make use of the new information.